# When is some memory "close" to the processor?

Tags: multithreading, performance, caching, memory, cpu

Because of the relatively slow RAM (compared to the CPU) in an average computer, optimal memory usage is important. I roughly understand how caches are used to mask the bad memory performance.

I keep reading that it is important that memory is kept close to the processor to achieve good performance. What exactly does it mean to have memory "close" to the processor? Does this refer to caching memory (cache being closer to the processor)? Or is there actually a difference in access speed between different parts of the main memory?

Comment: Probably it means physically closer. ;) Anyway `optimal memory usage is important` yes, if you are a hardware/os developer. Other then that noone cares. It's XXI century, we don't have to think about such things anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical memory architecture consists of the following levels:

- CPU registers
- L1 cache
- L2 cache
- L3 cache
- RAM attached to the same CPU socket
- RAM attached to other CPU sockets

The memory access times decrease in this order. The adjective "close" refers to this order, e.g. the L1 cache is closer than the L2 cache.

If performance matters, you should keep the memory *as close as possible* to the processor core. However, the adjective "close" on its own is confusing.

Comment: For recent Intel high performance x86 chips, L3 is sliced so that there is a section local to each "node" and other slices have additional delay based on how many hops are required on the ring interconnect. In a similar manner, with multiple memory controllers, a more distant but still on-chip memory controller might have *slightly* higher latency. These factors are not especially significant, but they seemed worth mentioning for greater completeness.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to the cache. Try searching for L1,L2,L3 caches. L1 is the closest, ie when the CPU wants to look up some data in memory, it will access the closest one(L1) and check. If not found here, it would go to subsequently lower levels and finally main memory(RAM) and then to the secondary memory(harddisk).
Typically memory closer to CPU will be smaller yet faster and farther ones will be larger and slower